# What is wrong with this UPDATE?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Why this code doesn't update?

```
UPDATE hr.employees SET salary = 1000
    WHERE employee_id NOT IN (SELECT distinct manager_id from hr.employees);
    commit;
```

I think the problem is about NOT IN.

Comment: Re-tagged with `oracle` as there is no PL/SQL involved here.

Comment: Can `manager_id` contain null values? Btw: the `distinct` is useless in the sub-query

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` has peculiar semantics.  When `manager_id` takes on a `NULL` value, then the expression always returns either `NULL` or `FALSE` for all rows.  That is, it will filter out all rows.

You can directly fix this by doing:

```
UPDATE hr.employees
    SET salary = 1000
    WHERE employee_id NOT IN (SELECT manager_id from hr.employees WHERE manager_id is not null);
```

(The `distinct` is not needed either.)

In my opinion, a better approach is to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` when you have a subquery.

```
UPDATE hr.employees
    SET salary = 1000
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from hr.employees e WHERE e.manager_id = employees.employee_id);
```

This behaves in the more intuitive way when `manager_id` could be `NULL`.